# Mongodb unique numeric value for record without explicitly writing logic to auto increment

Tags: .net, mongodb

For Mongodb I am looking to one unique numeric field in the document which will be auto increment and will be unique for all the records in the document, please note I don’t want to explicitly write logic to auto increment.

Can anyone please help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have a code for this as I am not sure how to do it.